# Why doesn't my selected value from SQLite database put into a python variable not equal the same string in a different variable?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm a beginner programmer and am tinkering with a login system with flask and SQLite3. The user inputs information from an HTML form and that form gets put into my database table named logins. The input works great and inputs data into the database, however when I try to select the data from the database, I am able to print a specific value with this:

```py
rows = c.execute("SELECT password FROM logins")
```

Where password is is a column in the database. That part works fine. However, when I try to put a single cell into a python variable, for example like into userCheck below, my if logic doesn't work in comparing the two values. If both username userCheck and password passCheck are the same, it still won't be True.

```py
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("login.html")
    else:
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        userCheck = c.execute("SELECT password FROM logins WHERE username = (?)", (username,))
        passCheck = c.execute("SELECT username FROM logins WHERE password = (?)", (password,))
        if username == userCheck and password == passCheck:
            return redirect("/")
        else: 
            error = "Username and Password don't match"
    return render_template("login.html", error=error)
```

I've been stuck on this for a bit so any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must fetch the result of the database, like below:

```py
userCheck = c.execute("SELECT password FROM logins WHERE username = (?)", (username,)).fetchall()[0][0]
passCheck = c.execute("SELECT username FROM logins WHERE password = (?)", (password,)).fetchall()[0][0]
```

Comment: When I use .fetchall()[0] the value that is returned prints as (password,) and (username,) instead of the intended "password" and "username". How do I fix this?